# Setting Custom ItemTitle in pagination in dojo grid

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

while using pagination in dojo grid 1.9,  I am not able to change the itemTitle in current position section. I found some examples for setting itemTitle but not working in dojo1.9. Can anyone help me out of this?

[Link of example](https://bitbucket.org/dojo/dojox/src/64328839903b/grid/tests/enhanced/test_enhanced_grid_pagination.html#cl-4)

Answer (score 0):

me too, perhaps you can edit the file
dojo1.9.1/dojox/grid/enhanced/nls/[your_lang]/Pagination.js

Comment: Thanks but I have multiple grids for users, employers, providers and so on. If i changed item title in Pagination.js, all grids will have same itemTitle. What I need is 1-10 users, 1-50 employers and so on.