# gridx pagination summary description - how to change format

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

Is there any way to the change the summary description that is displayed when Pagination is enabled on the gridx control?

It says 'Total 100' Whereas on the enhanced grid it would say 1-20 of 100 items

Can this description be tailored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Pagination.html) say that "the user can specify the string to use to display", but it's not shown how to do this. Maybe poking around the source can help you out.
Also here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023185/setting-custom-itemtitle-in-pagination-in-dojo-grid).